# Use a subset of system fonts for LibreOffice, on GNU/Linux

Tags: linux, debian, fonts, libreoffice, openoffice

I have a lot of system fonts in my GNU/Linux distribution (in `/usr/share/fonts/`): most of them are useless for me when I'm using LibreOffice to write or to open a document.

I'm using my distribution LibreOffice (obtained by `apt` from the officials Debian 12 repos).

**How can I make LibreOffice to only use/show some selected fonts?**

---

Please, note that **I shouldn't uninstall** these system fonts as they are used by other software and **I prefer** to stay with the LibreOffice package from my distribution.

---

I tried, without success, to:

- Inspect the parameters of LibreOffice:

  - Nothing but replacement tables in LibreOffice/Fonts
  - Nothing but default font in LibreOffice Writer/Standard Fonts
- Look for interesting CLI parameters with `libreoffice -h` : no success

I was thinking that it may be possible to present an alternative font folder to LibreOffice, should I chroot LibreOffice? Is it not overkill?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that a dedicated Linux **namespace** could be a possible solution. Tools like [Firejail](https://firejail.wordpress.com/) can even be used for this purpose.

On your system, the fonts are primarily stored in `/usr/share/fonts/`, but in addition to that system-wide directory, the user can also have their own fonts in: `/home/user/.local/share/fonts` if I'm correct.
Libre Office should also load fonts from that directory, if present.

The `fc-list` tool can be used to list available fonts.

So the idea would be to set up some kind of virtual file system where the main fonts directory (`/usr/share/fonts/`) is missing, but the folder holding the user-specific fonts is visible.

I haven't tried it but that looks perfectly doable.